# Ionic themes change dynamically

Tags: ionic-framework, themes, ionic4

In my `themes/variables.scss` I have two color themes (dark and light):

```
/* LIGHT COLOR THEMES
========================================= */
/*$colors: (
  primary: #ffffff,
  secondary: #fafafa,
  danger: #f53d3d,
  light: #1b1e28,
  sliderColor: #fff,
  colorIcon: #CCCBDA,
  colorIconText: #7F7E96,
  category: #fff,
  listBackgroundColor: #ffffff,
  backgroundColor: #fafafa,
  toobarBackground: #ffffff,
  toobarButton: #AAB2B7,
  toobarText: #FFFFFF
);*/



/* DARK COLOR THEMES
========================================= */
 $colors: (
   primary: #282C39,
   secondary: #1b1e28,
   danger: #f53d3d,
   sliderColor: #fff,
   light: #fff,
   colorIcon: #7F7E96,
   colorIconText: #7F7E96,
   category: #fff,
   listBackgroundColor: #1B1E28,
   backgroundColor: #282C39,
   toobarBackground: #1B1E28,
   toobarButton: #D8D8D8,
   toobarText: #FFFFFF
 );
```

Right now I can only put one theme in my app. If I want to change the theme, I have to comment the one variable out and the other I have to remove the comments.

How can I using these two themes, change the theme dynamically in the app in typescript?

In every tutorial I see these `--ion-color-primary` but I do not have these `--ion-color` prepending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a couple of ways. The main idea is that define your colors class. you can have for example -

```
// light theme
:root {
  // define your light colors here
}

// dark theme
:root body.dark {
  // define you dark colors here
}
```

So by default, the light theme will be applied, as the `<body>` of you application does not hold any class. Now to apply dark theme you just simply add class `dark` to the `<body>` of you application. For example, you can have a service for that which simply selects the body and adds the class to it. And remove it to go back to light theme.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThemeService {

  constructor() { }

  applyDark() {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('dark');
  }

  removeDark() {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('dark');
  }
}
```

By the way, I see you are using you own color variable. I've just given the example using the default ionic variables (from `src/theme/variables.scss`)

Comment: I have define : `:root {
 --ion-color-primary: #282C39;
 --ion-color-secondary: #1b1e28; ... }`

 but I am getting:

`[10:52:02]  sass: node_modules/ionic-angular/themes/ionic.functions.scss, line: 35 
            The value `` must be a color. If you are setting the value as a map make sure both the base and contrast are 
            defined as colors. For example: $colors: ( primary: #327eff, secondary: (base: #32db64, contrast: #000), ); 

      L35:    @error $error-msg;`

Comment: I cannot understand from this error code. What is on line: 35. I recommend you to go through the documentation (https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/themes)